# Adjusting layouts for different screen sizes for API 14-17, 17-30, 30+

Tags: java, android, margins, screen-size, layoutparams

***EDIT 09.05.2021:***

In general, I would like to programatically adjust the `LayoutParams` of some Buttons depending on the display size of the smartphone by adjusting some geometry values in `onCreate()`. Apparently it's not quite that simple.

Finally found found an approach for that, which is *possibly* working between API 14-17, 17-30, 30+.

My goal would be to determine the "real screen size" without insets / navigation bar elements for all APIs between 14-30+.

I still have to adapt the approach for < API 17, as the navigation bar elements may not yet be deducted in this case (I am currently trying to determine the navigation bar size for these use cases).

---

***QUERY OF THE SCREENSIZE (width, height):***

```
 //++++++++++++++ DISPLAY SIZES +++++++++++++

DisplayMetrics realDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

int realDisplayWidth;
int realDisplayHeight;

//++++++++++++++ GET HORIZONTAL SCREENSIZE +++++++++

public int getRealScreenWidth(){

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        // TARGETING BUILDVERSIONS GREATER EQUAL API:30

        WindowMetrics windowMetrics = getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics();
        // HORIZONTAL DISPLAY SIZE INCLUDING INSETS

        WindowInsets windowInsets = windowMetrics.getWindowInsets();
        Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
                | WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout());

        int insetsWidth = insets.right + insets.left;
        // GET THE SIZE OF HORIZONTAL INSETS

        Rect bounds = windowMetrics.getBounds();
        realDisplayWidth = bounds.width() - insetsWidth;
        // HORIZONTAL SCREEN SIZE WITHOUT INSETS

        return realDisplayWidth;

    }

    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        // TARGETING BUILDVERSIONS ABOVE API:17, UNTIL API:30

        Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        display.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics);
        realDisplayWidth = realDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;

        return realDisplayWidth;
    }

    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        //REFLECTION FOR BUILDVERSIONs ABOVE API:14 UNTIL API:17

        Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        try {
            Method getHorizontalSize = Display.class.getMethod("getWidth");
            realDisplayWidth = (Integer) getHorizontalSize.invoke(display);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            realDisplayWidth = 1000;
        }
        return realDisplayWidth;
    }
    else {
    return realDisplayWidth = 1000;
    }
}

//++++++++++++++ GET VERTICAL SCREENSIZE +++++++++

public int getRealScreenHeight(){

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        // TARGETING BUILDVERSIONS GREATER EQUAL API:30

        WindowMetrics windowMetrics = getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics();
        // VERTICAL DISPLAY SIZE INCLUDING INSETS

        WindowInsets windowInsets = windowMetrics.getWindowInsets();
        Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
                | WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout());

        int insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom;
        // GET THE SIZE OF VERTICAL INSETS

        Rect bounds = windowMetrics.getBounds();
        realDisplayHeight = bounds.height() - insetsHeight;
        // HORIZONTAL SCREEN SIZE WITHOUT INSETS

        return realDisplayHeight;

    }

    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        // TARGETING BUILDVERSIONS ABOVE API:17, UNTIL API:30

        Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        display.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics);
        realDisplayHeight = realDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;

        return realDisplayHeight;
    }

    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        //REFLECTION FOR BUILDVERSIONs ABOVE API:14 UNTIL API:17

        Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        try {
            Method getVerticalSize = Display.class.getMethod("getHeight");
            realDisplayHeight = (Integer) getVerticalSize.invoke(display);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            realDisplayHeight = 1500;
        }
        return realDisplayHeight;
    }
    else {
        return realDisplayHeight = 1500;
    }
}

public void getLog(){
    Log.i("screenWide:", String.valueOf(getRealScreenWidth()));
    Log.i("screenHeight:", String.valueOf(getRealScreenHeight()));
}
```

---

***CHANGING LAYOUTPARAMS:***

```
//++++++++++++++ EXAMPLE METHOD FOR CHANGING PARAMS IN ONCREATE() ++++++++++

public void changingLayoutParams(){

    // EXAMPLE FOR CHANGING HORIZONTAL LAYOUT PARAMS FOR API ABOVE 17:

    Button number1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number1);
    Button sidebar_v_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sidebar_v_1);

    if (getRealScreenWidth() >= 1000){

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) number1.getLayoutParams();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            params.setMarginStart((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.levelSymbolLeftMargin));
            params.setMargins(params.getMarginStart(), params.topMargin, params.getMarginEnd(), params.bottomMargin);
        }

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params2 = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) sidebar_v_1.getLayoutParams();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            params2.setMarginStart((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.levelSymbolLeftMargin));
            params2.setMargins(params2.getMarginStart(), params2.topMargin, params2.getMarginEnd(), params2.bottomMargin);
        }
    }
    else if (getRealScreenWidth() < 1000){

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) number1.getLayoutParams();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            params.setMarginStart((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.lockerMarginLeft));
            params.setMargins(params.getMarginStart(), params.topMargin, params.getMarginEnd(), params.bottomMargin);
        }

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params2 = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) sidebar_v_1.getLayoutParams();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            params2.setMarginStart((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.lockerMarginLeft));
            params2.setMargins(params2.getMarginStart(), params2.topMargin, params2.getMarginEnd(), params2.bottomMargin);
        }
    }

}
```

---

I have built a `ConstraintLayout` with several nested layouts inside, with the following rough structure (reduced amount of elements inside):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/outerBlock"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/nestedScroll_mR"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/nestedScroll_mR"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nestedScroll_mL"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/nestedScroll_mL"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nestedScroll_mT"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/nestedScroll_mB"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/innerBlock0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/firstInnerBlockH"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/innerBlock1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/innerBlockH"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/innerBlock0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/number1"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/levelSymbol"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/levelSymbol"
                    android:background="@drawable/number1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/numberMarginTop"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/numberMarginLeft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/numberMarginLeft"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sidebar_v_1"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/sidebarVWidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/sidebarVHeight"
                    android:background="@drawable/side_v"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/sideMarginLeft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/sideMarginLeft"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/number1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/innerBlock2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/innerBlockH"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/innerBlock1">

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

By changing the `marginLeft` and `marginStart` `LayoutParam` the layout would better fit into the display. At the beginning i just designed it for 1 screensize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you're trying to change the margin values of 2 buttons in onCreate(). This will have the same effect as changing the margin values in your activity_main.xml file.

If you're trying to do something else, for instance, change these values when you click a button, you can just set an onClickListener to another button, and then put this code in that onClick listener. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: That was just an example code with less code (actually there are >100 views+button).

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make sense to do this in onCreate(), when you can do the same thing much simpler in your xml file. It will have the same effect.

Comment: Basically, your approach has a very correct component: Not to complicate something if there is a simpler way.

I have been able to standardise the layout so that it is suitable for all common display sizes.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it. Sorry I wasn't able to help out with the LayoutParams problems.